# add onclick confirm to existing <a> tag that has inline JavaScript that doPostBack

Tags: javascript

As the title shows, I want to add an onclick confirm  to an existing  tag that raises post-back by inline JavaScript inside the "href" attribute after clicking the img

```
<a href="JavaScript: _doPostBack(/*some arguments here*/)">
    <img src="mysrc" />
</a>
```

I am wondering how to achieve that, currently I am thinking to add "onclientclick" that handles the confirm.

But will this raise the post-back event after user choose 'yes'? Or am i doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: What do you want to validate here?

Comment: @Luca Something based on client choice like `return Confirm("Proceed?");`

Comment: So you don't want to do any validation, but just get confirmation on something?

Comment: @Luca Yes, maybe i need to edit the question

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: So, add a click event handler, and prevent the event "default action", which in this case would be the execution of `"JavaScript: _doPostBack()..."` - https://jsfiddle.net/u8j9uhhv/5/ ... where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @CBroe I am wondering how to add the confirm before the post-back occurs that would prevent the post-back if the user clicks cancel

Comment: @CBroe Will keep your suggestion as the backup method, thanks for mentioning. But currently I just want to insert that confirm progress before the post-back occurs

Comment: That's what my example does ... watch the console as you either confirm or cancel the dialog!

Comment: @CBroe oh, ok sorry about that, maybe i didn't get your word. After looking into the fiddle, I get what you mean. Thank you again